# VideoCapture not working error in Installing OpenCV 2.4.13 or 3.x on Fedora 26 25 24 23 or 22 with ffmpeg and python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, opencv, computer-vision

When I use yum, it installs opencv 3.2.0. But I specifically need opencv 2.4.13.

With Anaconda, there is a conda-forge package of opencv but installing that cv2.VideoCapture() api fails.

Also when I am trying to install through tar file of opencv 2.4.13, I am stuck in cmake, getting below errors -

**sys/videoio.h not found**

**libavcodec not found**

**........**

Also cmake is giving bizzare scripting errors. 
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Anaconda does not have opencv 2.4.13 compiled with ffmpeg, so if you want to use VideoCapture then opencv needs to be compiled.
Descriptive list of steps I followed **(strictly for fedora users)**:

**Remove previous opencv**

```
sudo yum remove opencv
```

**Install Python 2.7**

```
sudo yum install python2.7
```

*Please use your python 2.7 package name.

**Installation of ffmpeg**

Download tarball from their site and extract it.
https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

```
tar -xvf ffmpeg-3.3.0.tar.gz
cd ffmpeg-3.3.0
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter-lavf
```

*remove option --enable-avfilter-lavf if it gives error.

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

**Installation of OpenCV 2.4.13**

Below packages will solve sys/videoio.h error:

```
sudo dnf install pjproject-devel.x86_64 2.4.5-8.fc26     ptlib-devel.x86_64 2.10.10-16.fc24     pjproject.x86_64 2.4.5-8.fc26     ptlib.x86_64 2.10.10-16.fc24
```

Then install these packages:

```
sudo yum install libpng-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel jasper-devel openexr-devel libtiff-devel libwebp-devel libdc1394-devel libv4l-devel gstreamer-plugins-base-devel gtk2-devel tbb-devel eigen3-devel gstreamer1-libav gstreamer1-plugins-base-devel java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 python2-numpy.x86_64 ffmpeg-devel.x86_64 ffmpeg-libs.i686 ffmpeg.x86_64 libavdevice.i686 libpng-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel jasper-devel openexr-devel libtiff-devel libwebp-devel libdc1394-devel libv4l-devel gstreamer-plugins-base-devel gtk2-devel tbb-devel eigen3-devel gstreamer1-libav gstreamer1-plugins-base-devel gtk+extra-devel.x86_64 gtk+-devel.i686 cmake pkg-config libgtk libavcodec libavformat libswscale swig
```

Download OpenCV of your choice e.g. 2.4.13 from github (select 2.4.13 from Branch -> Tags -> 2.4.13 then chose download from clone):

https://github.com/opencv/opencv

http://opencv.org/releases.html

Extract tar:

```
tar -xvf opencv-2.4.13.3.tar.gz
cd opencv-2.4.13.3
mkdir build; cd build;
```

Now **cmake**:

```
sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local  -D WITH_FFMPEG=1  -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_V4L=OFF -D CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic -DLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/ -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$(python -c "import distutils.sysconfig as sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR'))") -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-ccbin /home/rishabh/gcc-4.9.4-x86_64/bin/gcc" -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpu=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpuarithm=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpubgsegm=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpucodec=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpufeatures2d=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpufilters=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpuimgproc=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpulegacy=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpuoptflow=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpustereo=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpuwarping=OFF -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF ..
```

**Explanation** :

Flags that include 'gpu' text are for turning off gpu compilation, if you want to compile with gpu then set them ON. But gpu will require cuda packages and a graphics card to work.

This flag can also be ignored since we are not compiling with gpu, but it also didn't hurt me keeping it.

-DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-ccbin /home/rishabh/gcc-4.9.4-x86_64/bin/gcc"

**If you are facing script errors in cmake then do these-**

open file opencv-2.4.13.3/cmake/OpenCVPackaging.cmake

-- add this

```
set(OPENCV_VCSVERSION "2.4.13.3")
```

-- above this line

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "${OPENCV_VCSVERSION}")
```

Comment out respective lines that are blocking cmake and are useless, in whatever filename is thrown out on console.

e.g. opencv-2.4.13.3/cmake/OpenCVDetectCXXCompiler.cmake

I had problem with line 80-86 so I commented it out because those variables were not doing anything else elsewhere.

**After cmake is successful, proceed to make step -**

```
sudo make 
sudo make install
```

If you are facing any linker errors then you will have to install respective dependencies or set cmake flag to OFF if you do not intend to install those modules.

**Post installation steps:**

```
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc 
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now add

```
/usr/local/lib/
```

to following files:

```
/etc/ld.so.conf
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf
```

Now run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

**For Anaconda PATH variable Conflict**

remove anaconda path from PATH variable and edit in ~/.bashrc also

export PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/cuda/bin:/home/rishabh/.local/bin:/home/rishabh/bin:/opt/cuda/bin/

**Now logout and login to fedora**.

**Execute below for Testing:**

```
python
import cv2
cv2.__version__
video = cv2.VideoCapture("your small video.mp4")
okay, frame = video.read()
print("VideoCapture Read Success - ")
print(okay)
```

**Output**-

True - video read success

False - opencv yet not compiled properly with ffmpeg.